# Мониторинг нагрузки на таблицы в MySQL

Tags: mysql, битрикс

Можно ли как-то в режиме онлайн отслеживать нагрузку на все или отдельные **таблицы** MySQL. Цель: отследить, какая именно таблица при накате обновлений "забивается" неизвестными данными до тех пор, пока на hdd не кончится место.

Портал: Битрикс. 
ОС: CentOS

Comment: Во-первых, есть General log. Во-вторых, есть триггеры. Но лучше покопаться в потрохах обновления. А ещё лучше - адресовать проблему авторам этого обновления.

Comment: Авторы обновления помочь не хотят, пока им не предоставишь информацию о том, какая из таблиц растет в размерах.

Comment: *пока им не предоставишь информацию о том, какая из таблиц растет в размерах.* А посмотреть тупо в файловой системе? или у Вас `innodb_file_per_table` отключен?

Answer (score 1):

А не проще после наката обновлений просто через [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) или [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) отсортировать таблицы по размеру и подозрительно большие просмотреть в ручную. 
можно еще через профайлер в базе отследить insert запросы посмотреть в какую таблицу их больше всего валиться.

Comment: Обновления просто забивают базу данных до размеров hdd, но так и не накатываются. Можно до бесконечности ждать увеличивать память, но обновления так и не установятся, сожрав все место на жестком. Примечательно, что если в процессе установки сделать service mysqld restart, то размер память возвращается в прежнее состояние. Но я попробую, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Я бы рекомендовал использовать Workbench (https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).
MySQL Workbench — инструмент для визуального проектирования баз данных, интегрирующий проектирование, моделирование, создание и эксплуатацию БД в единое бесшовное окружение для системы баз данных MySQL.

Comment: Спасибо. Установил. Возможностей и правда много. Пока не разобрался, как мне мониторить нагрузку на таблицы...